# monitoring dual boot machines in nagios

Tags: nagios

We're currently planning on dual booting some of our servers (different IP and hostnames). So, is it possible in nagios to put a condition wherein a dual boot machine won't send an alarm signal provided that the dual boot OS is up?

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do it please? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried it myself, but you can try configuring specific service dependencies: 
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/dependencies.html making it so that if host A is active, then state of host B is not checked and vice versa.

Alternatively, if this doesn't work, you should be able to make custom event handling scripts, which enable/disable the other service checking upon state change of the first service, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I'll forward this to our IT Staff. This would surely help :)